# PostgreSQL how to avoid duplicate rows with same date when adding a windows function and groupby

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to understand how to avoid PSQL duplicate rows when I'm applying a windows function and adding a `groupBy`.

I created a DBfiddle very simple but was unable to reproduce the issue there, however, is  a starting point

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sxrYeclH)

When I apply my below query to extract my data in a certain way the resulting data have one duplicate row per day with 0, 0, 0 as I want to avoid that row being displayed.

The query purpose is to show numbers from how many candidates we have every day:

- *current* indicates the current candidates
- *total* indicates the full total of candidates
- *difference* indicates the total difference between the total of today day and the day before (the windows function is applied here in the query)

Here is my full query and I notice that if I remove the below windows function and total from `groupby` the dates are not duplicated, so I believe there is an error here

```
COALESCE(total - LAG(total, 2) OVER (ORDER BY day) - 0, 0) AS difference
```

```sql
SELECT
    "candidates"."day" AS "day",
    "candidates"."study_id" AS "studyId",
    "candidates"."status" AS "status",
    sum("current") AS "current",
    sum("total") AS "total",
    COALESCE(total - LAG(total, 2) OVER (ORDER BY day) - 0, 0) AS difference
FROM
    "candidates"
WHERE
    "study_id" in('CY')
    AND "status" in('PENDING_CALLCENTER')
GROUP BY
    "day",
    "study_id",
    "status",
    total
ORDER BY
    "day" ASC,
    "study_id" ASC,
    "status" ASC
```

The results of the query and the orange arrows show the duplicated rows which I need to hide. As you see ar like `date 0 0 0` and then we have the same date but with the right numbers.

Honestly, cannot understand how to avoid that.

[image]

Resulting in data removing the windows function and total from groupby

[image: Result]

Comment: `total` in the `GROUP BY` clause is the cause.  Remove that.

Comment: When I remove I have this column "candidates.total" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: `COALESCE(SUM(total) - LAG(SUM(total), 2) OVER ...` .. since you need to refer to the aggregate first.

Comment: You probably didn't want `2` either.  That was probably because of the other mistake with total in the GROUP BY clause.  You wanted the difference in the adjacent rows.  Now they are adjacent.  I suppose this should be in the form of an answer, for others who read the post.

Comment: Yes right also 2 no need for perfect appreciated the help :)

Comment: It would have helped for the sample data to produce the problem behavior.  The updated fiddle (in the answer) contains a couple of candidate rows with 0 total, which must have been in the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`total` in the `GROUP BY` clause causes the extra groups to be generated.  To remove that we also need to refer to the `SUM(total)` aggregate in the select list and also adjust `LAG` to refer to the prior adjacent row. The `- 0` operation is also not necessary.

Here's the [updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dC26zduA) with data which reproduces the extra row issue, plus the corrected SQL.

```sql
SELECT
    "candidates"."day" AS "day",
    "candidates"."study_id" AS "studyId",
    "candidates"."status" AS "status",
    sum("current") AS "current",
    sum("total") AS "total",
    COALESCE(SUM(total) - LAG(SUM(total)) OVER (ORDER BY day), 0) AS difference
FROM
    "candidates"
WHERE
    "study_id" in('CY')
    AND "status" in('PENDING_CALLCENTER')
GROUP BY
    "day",
    "study_id",
    "status"
ORDER BY
    "day" ASC,
    "study_id" ASC,
    "status" ASC
;
```

Result prior to the correction:

| day | studyId | status | current | total | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-13 01:00:00+01 | CY | PENDING_CALLCENTER | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-13 01:00:00+01 | CY | PENDING_CALLCENTER | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-04-14 01:00:00+01 | CY | PENDING_CALLCENTER | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-14 01:00:00+01 | CY | PENDING_CALLCENTER | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-04-15 01:00:00+01 | CY | PENDING_CALLCENTER | 0 | 3 | 3 |
| 2021-04-16 01:00:00+01 | CY | PENDING_CALLCENTER | 10 | 14 | 12 |
| 2021-04-17 01:00:00+01 | CY | PENDING_CALLCENTER | 0 | 15 | 12 |

Result after the correction:

| day | studyId | status | current | total | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-13 01:00:00+01 | CY | PENDING_CALLCENTER | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-04-14 01:00:00+01 | CY | PENDING_CALLCENTER | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-04-15 01:00:00+01 | CY | PENDING_CALLCENTER | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| 2021-04-16 01:00:00+01 | CY | PENDING_CALLCENTER | 10 | 14 | 11 |
| 2021-04-17 01:00:00+01 | CY | PENDING_CALLCENTER | 0 | 15 | 1 |

The setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "public"."candidates" (
    "day" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "study_id" varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    "site_id" varchar(32),
    "status" varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    "total" int4 NOT NULL,
    "current" int4 NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO "public"."candidates" ("day", "study_id", "site_id", "status", "total", "current") VALUES
('2021-04-13 00:00:00+00', 'CY', 'BEL-1', 'PENDING_CALLCENTER', 0, 0),
('2021-04-13 00:00:00+00', 'CY', 'BEL-1', 'PENDING_CALLCENTER', 1, 0),
('2021-04-14 00:00:00+00', 'CY', 'ESP-1', 'PENDING_CALLCENTER', 0, 0),
('2021-04-14 00:00:00+00', 'CY', 'ESP-1', 'PENDING_CALLCENTER', 2, 0),
('2021-04-15 00:00:00+00', 'CY', 'SWE-1', 'PENDING_CALLCENTER', 3, 0),
('2021-04-16 00:00:00+00', 'CY', 'USA-1', 'PENDING_CALLCENTER', 14, 10),
('2021-04-17 00:00:00+00', 'CY', NULL, 'PENDING_CALLCENTER', 15, 0),
('2021-04-18 00:00:00+00', 'CY', 'BEL-1', 'REJECTED_CALLCENTER', 25, 0),
('2021-04-19 00:00:00+00', 'CY', 'ESP-1', 'REJECTED_CALLCENTER', 50, 0),
('2021-04-20 00:00:00+00', 'CY', 'SWE-1', 'REJECTED_CALLCENTER', 67, 0),
('2021-04-21 00:00:00+00', 'CY', 'USA-1', 'REJECTED_CALLCENTER', 90, 0)
;
```

Comment: @nbk See the updated fiddle.  That is addressed also with the `SUM(total)` aggregate expressions.

Comment: @nbk The poster admitted that the fiddle did not reproduce the problem.  The data was not sufficient.  I added data, which must have been present in the actual table to reproduce the issue.  Look closely at the first result rows 1 and 3 in my fiddle.  Those are the extra rows the poster did not want in the result.  Removing `total` from `GROUP BY` and adding the proper `SUM` aggregate did solve that issue.

Comment: Perfect explanation and learned something new great help much appreciated :)